# Disable iframe redirection, but show the page

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, redirect

I am working on a website, that displays different traffic exchanges to surf multiple sites at the same time. But I have some problem with sweeva. If I set the src of the iframe to sweeva.com/sweeve, it redirects the top/parent window to the same url. I can block the redirection, but I can't see the page itself.

Is there any way to detect and disable the script, that redirects, but display the site?

Or is there some way to not to tell that it is in an iframe?

Comment: In Google Chrome there is no redirection, but it doesn't show the site

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: no. If the page you are trying to put in an frame (iframe, object, etc) has "frame-busting" code in it then you can only stop the redirect. But you can't show the content.

Comment: Do you think this code? 

var breaker = 1; var prevent_bust = 0;setInterval(function() { if (prevent_bust > 0 && breaker > 0) { prevent_bust -= 2; window.top.location = 'http://www.sweeva.com/sweeve/nobreak.php'; } }, 131); window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++; }

Is it possible to replace it with onbeforeload event and innerHTML?